# Fetching data from two tables matching a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the two tables' schema:

```
1) Person(name varchar(100),income int)

2) IncomeGroups(incomeGroupName varchar(100), minIncome int, maxIncome int)
```

I was stumbled while developing a sql query for fetching Person Names with their IncomeGroupNames based on their income.

I am trying to accomplish something like (Name,IncomeGroupName).

Is it even possible? I'll be really glad if anyone can guide me in this.

Comment: Thanks all, I didnt knew we can use Joins that way, was just ignorant about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.Name, b.IncomeGroupName
FROM    Person a
        INNER JOIN IncomeGroups b
            ON a.income BETWEEN b.minIncome AND b.maxIncome
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Additional information, if you want to list all person even if the income does not fall on any range, change `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query which joins the tables:

```
select p.name,
  i.incomeGroupName
from person p
inner join incomegroups i
  on p.income >= i.minIncome
  and p.income <= i.maxIncome;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cc3c/1)

This joins the tables based on the range that the person's income falls in.